# Matrix for rounding to the nearest whole number

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

> There are two barbers in a town. Of the people who go to the 'good' barber, $92\%$ will go to the good barber again the next time. Of the people who go to the 'bad' barber, $18\%$ will go to the bad barber again the next time. On January 1<sup>st</sup>, out of $100$ people, $58$ of them went to the good barber and $42$ went to the bad barber. Everyone gets a haircut on the first of each month.
>
> a) How many people will be going to each barber on February 1<sup>st</sup>?
> b) What matrix calculation would you have to do to determine the number of people going to each barber on July 1<sup>st</sup>? (Just write the expression, don't calculate it.)
> c) After enough time, the number of people going to each barber will 'stabilise.' How many people out the 100 will be going to the good barber at that point?

a) $$\begin{bmatrix}.92(58)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}53.36\end{bmatrix}=53\\\begin{bmatrix}.18(42)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7.56\end{bmatrix}=8$$

b) $$\begin{bmatrix}.92&0\\0&.18\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}58\\42\end{bmatrix}$$

c) $$58\to53\to49\to\cdots\\[5pt]\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}.92X\end{bmatrix}=X\implies x-.5\le.92&x<x+.5\\-.5\le-.08&x<.5\\6.25\ge\;&x>-6.25\\&\boxed{x=6}\end{align}$$

Having trouble with part b. Is there a way to get a matrix calculation to round to the nearest integer?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about rounding. Note that you shouldn't have zeroes though. Remember that there is still a probability that people switch barbers (that is, the columns should each add up to one). So $n$ months after January First, we want to compute:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.92 & 0.82 \\
0.08 & 0.18
\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}
58 \\ 42
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Ah, I fundamentally misunderstood the problem. I didn't realize that the people that left the good barber would go to the bad barber and vice versa.